# Toggle fully qualified Go type names to see variable values in Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm debugging Go code in Visual Studio Code and I don't have a large screen. The result is I can't see any of the variable values in the debug view because the type names are things like `github.com/companyname/project/some/deep/folder/maybe/Variable`. Is there a toggle to shorten these? I've looked for a while and can't see any.

Answer (score 1):

Use `compact` view of variables in debug configuration:

#### launch.json

```
"showCompact": true,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer  but this option errors for me  `property showCompact isn't allowed`